# How to setHeaderFilterValue (Tabulator) with two values, min and max?

Tags: javascript, filter, header, tabulator

I have a table featuring an "age" column with a min and max filter editor following this [Tabulator documentation ("Progress" column](https://tabulator.info/examples/4.8#filter-header).

I would like to programmatically set the header filter value of "age" to between say, 20 and 40.

```js
table.setHeaderFilterValue("age", 20); //This will set both the min and max to value 20.
```

Is is possible to do something like this?

```js
table.setHeaderFilterValue("age", [20, 40]);
```

Or any alternatives for that? I read about `setFilter` but I would like to see the value being applied at the header filter for users to see, just like how `setHeaderFilterValue` works on other single value columns.

Let me know if there are references that I miss out and if I need to provide additional information. Thank you.